# Expected square difference determines the distribution of a Gaussian random vector

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading a result which states that for a Gaussian random vector $(X_{1},\dots, X_{n})$, with $EX_{i}=0$ and $EX_{i}^{2}=1$ for all $i$,

the metric $d(i,j)=(E(X_{i}-X_{j})^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ determines the distribution of $X$.

Why is this the case? I am thinking it somehow involves the triangle inequality...

Answer (score 1):

The normal (Gaussian) distribution is fully characterized by it's mean and covariance matrix. In your case, the mean is $0$, the diagonal elements of $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ are $1$'s, and for $i\ne j$,
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=\mathsf{E}X_iX_j=1-\frac{1}{2}[d(i,j)]^2.
$$

Comment: why is that true?

Comment: What exactly are u asking about?

Comment: That $EX_{i}X_{j}=1-\frac{1}{2}[d(i,j)]^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: $$
[d(i,j)]^2=\mathsf{E}[X_i-X_j]^2=\mathsf{E}X_i^2+\mathsf{E}X_j^2-2\mathsf{E}X_iX_j...
$$